# Format specifiers for uint8_t, uint16_t, ...?

Tags: c++, c++11, scanf

If I have an integer variable I can use `sscanf` as shown below by using the format specifier %d.

```
sscanf (line, "Value of integer: %d\n", &my_integer);
```

Where can I find format specifiers for `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`?

uint64_t has probably %lu.

Comment: Isn't `%lu` for `unsigned long`? That's often 32 bits.

Comment: No problem if you use iostreams instead, which adapt to the type

Comment: @MSalters: beware that for 64 bits targets, Windows 64 `unsigned long` is 32 bits, whereas all UNIX and Linux 64 bits `unsigned long` are 64 bits.

Comment: @Didier Trosset `unsigned long` is NOT 64 bit on all 64 bit UNIX variants. It's 32 bits on 64 bit solaris using gcc. I once had a painful experience learning that it's 64bits on linux.

Comment: @camelccc From what is explained there: http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html, 64 bit solaris ought to be an exception to UNIX being LP64.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

They are declared in `<inttypes.h>` as macros: SCNd8, SCNd16, SCNd32 and SCNd64.
Example  (for int32_t):

```
sscanf (line, "Value of integer: %" SCNd32 "\n", &my_integer);
```

Their format is PRI (for printf)/SCN (for scan) then o, u, x, X d, i for the corresponding specifier then nothing, LEAST, FAST, MAX then the size (obviously there is no size for MAX). Some other examples: PRIo8, PRIuMAX, SCNoFAST16.

Edit: BTW a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183679) asked why that method was used. You may find the answers interesting.

Comment: It should be `SCNu32` for `uint32_t`. `SCNi32` is for `int32_t`.

Comment: -1: They are not declared there, except as a non-standard extension.

Comment: @phresnel, a question about int8_t obviously assume either C++0X or an extension importing those from C99 before the standard does so.  In the first case, `<inttypes.h>` is present, in the second one, assuming the import of `<inttypes.h>` at the same time as `<stdint.h>` is a pretty safe bet for the implementation I know.

Comment: As this is a popular Q & A, suggest a comment about a tangential issue: the certainly problematic trailing `'\n'` in a `scanf()` format.

Answer (score 7):

As others said, include `<stdint.h>` header that defines the format macros. In C++, however, define `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` prior to including it. From stdint.h:

```
/* The ISO C99 standard specifies that these macros must only be
   defined if explicitly requested.  */
#if !defined __cplusplus || defined __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
```

Comment: And according to C++0X, "The macros defined by <cinttypes> are provided unconditionally. In particular, the symbol __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS, mentioned in footnote 182 of the C standard, plays no role in C++."  But defining __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS may helps with extensions not updated to follow C++0X.

Answer (score 2):

According to *7.19.6 Formatted input/output functions* of *ISO/IEC 9899:TC2*, there are no such format specifiers (so I doubt there any for C++2003). Even though there are some #define-macros available in C99's `inttypes.h`, `cinttypes` and `inttypes.h` are not part of the current standard. Of course, fixed-size integer types are non-standard as well.

Anyways, I seriously recommemend using streams instead:

```
<any_type> x;
f >> x;
```

and be done. E.g.:

```
std::stringstream ss;
uint32_t u;
std::cin >> u;
```

This has the advantage that one time in the future, changing the type of the variable does not cause a cascade of subtle bugs and undefined behaviour.

Comment: Using ">>" appears much slower than fscanf, 2-3 times on VC++ 2010

Comment: @sergtk: That's a feature. By default, iostreams are synced with C functions. You can disable this and the result will be that iostreams are as least as fast.

Comment: I suppose you mean std::ifstream.sync_with_stdio(false); . This does not improve speed reasonably. Moreover if string is read by << operator, then parsed with sscanf, then speed is almost the same as with fscanf. This means that parsing values is slower with iostream and this is not connected with sync.

Comment: @sergtk: Hmm, not in my benchmarks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9747716/76722 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212163/76722. And I am not sure why you want to use `<<`, then `sscanf` as an alternative to `fscanf`.

Comment: First link contains testing when chars are read, this does not involves converting types. Second link is more interesting since it already contains int-s. But we used different compilers. I tested mostly with int-s and float-s. Even more interesting that in fact all file reading in my testing is still with std::ifstream. But initially it was used to read any types with "<<". But optimised version reads strings with getline(ifstream&, string&), then parsed with sscanfs for strings. Performance improved just because using other conversion of types, not by optimising reading data.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the header is `<inttypes.h>`, and formats such as SCNX8, SCNd16.

The same header probably works for C++ too.

Comment: `<inttypes.h>` has been imported in the C++ standard at the same time as `<stdint.h>` (which declares the typedef `int8_t` and friends), formally in C++0X but in practice available as extension in implementations having a strong relationship with an implementation of C99.

Answer (score 0):

The right format to read a `uint64_t` (typedef unsigned long long int) is, with `scanf` and not `sscanf`, `"%" SCNu64` and for print is also `SCNu64`
Example. in your code you read for example my_integer variable, then you do 
`scanf ("Value of integer:%" SCNu64, & my_integer);` and to write the same but with printf.

Answer (score 0):

You can check types in `<cstdint>` for C++ or in `<types.h>` for C. Then you can specify format which is currently compiled on your machine.
If variable is `unsigned` then you need to use `%u`, if variable is `signed`, then use `%d`. For variables size lower than 32 bytes you don't have to specify long prefix.

In my configuration I have 64 bit program, so my `uint64_t` is compiled as `unsigned long long int`, so it means to use `%llu`. If your program will be compiled in 32 bit you can use `%lu` because `uint64_t` will be compiled as `unsigned long int`

But who is using x86 still? :), so generally:

```
uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t - %u
uint64_t - %llu
int8_t, int16_t, int32_t - %d
int64_t -%lld
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -2):

Refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) for sscanf usage.

These datatypes are defined in stdint.h. Refer [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html) for stdint.h

Shash

Comment: Refering is not answering. It primarily tells you don't know yourself.

Comment: I dont believe in copy, paste if it is available over net!! + This is like joining the dots, sscanf & stdint, dont you think ?

Comment: But stackoverflow answers should stay valid in itself. At least tell where at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/ it is mentioned how to format int64 et al.