# How do I print uint32_t and uint16_t variables' value?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to print an `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` value, but it is not giving the desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t a = 12, a1;
    uint16_t b = 1, b1;
    a1 = htonl(a);
    printf("%d---------%d", a1);
    b1 = htons(b);
    printf("\n%d-----%d", b, b1);
    return 0;
}
```

I also used

```
printf("%"PRIu32, a);
```

which is showing an error.

How do I print these values and what will be the desired output?

Comment: It would be much more helpful to show us the (exact!) error message rather than just saying that it's "showing error". And rather than just "not giving desired o/p", show us the actual output (and spell out the word "output" rather than writing "o/p").

Comment: `printf("%d---------%d",a1);` produces undefined behaviour because you have two %d in the format string but only pass one parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format specifiers for uint8\_t, uint16\_t, ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993132/format-specifiers-for-uint8-t-uint16-t)

Comment: all answeres using stdio, meanwhile i'm desperately trying to print via UART on an embedded system without libraries XD

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to include `inttypes.h` if you want all those nifty new format specifiers for the `intN_t` types and their brethren, and that *is* the correct (ie, portable) way to do it, provided your compiler complies with C99. You shouldn't use the standard ones like `%d` or `%u` in case the sizes are different to what you think.

It includes `stdint.h` and extends it with quite a few other things, such as the macros that can be used for the `printf/scanf` family of calls. This is covered in section 7.8 of the ISO C99 standard.

For example, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main (void) {
    uint32_t a=1234;
    uint16_t b=5678;
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n",a);
    printf("%" PRIu16 "\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
1234
5678
```

Answer (score 20):

The macros defined in `<inttypes.h>` are the most correct way to print values of types `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, and so forth -- but they're not the only way.

Personally, I find those macros difficult to remember and awkward to use. (Given the syntax of a `printf` format string, that's probably unavoidable; I'm not claiming I could have come up with a better system.)

An alternative is to cast the values to a predefined type and use the format for that type.

Types `int` and `unsigned int` are guaranteed by the language to be at least 16 bits wide, and therefore to be able to hold any converted value of type `int16_t` or `uint16_t`, respectively. Similarly, `long` and `unsigned long` are at least 32 bits wide, and `long long` and `unsigned long long` are at least 64 bits wide.

For example, I might write your program like this (with a few additional tweaks):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>  

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t a=12, a1;
    uint16_t b=1, b1;
    a1 = htonl(a);
    printf("%lu---------%lu\n", (unsigned long)a, (unsigned long)a1);
    b1 = htons(b);
    printf("%u-----%u\n", (unsigned)b, (unsigned)b1);
    return 0;
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that it can work even with pre-C99 implementations that don't support `<inttypes.h>`. Such an implementation most likely wouldn't have `<stdint.h>` either, but the technique is useful for other integer types.

Comment: There's one very minor edge case here, if signed int is not two's complement. In that case, it won't correctly hold the most negative two's complement value. VERY minor, I'll admit but something to watch out for if you want maximum portability.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The `intN_t` types are required to be two's-complement with no padding bits. If `int` is not two's-complement, then the `intN_t` types probably won't be defined *unless* the implementation supports distinct two's-complement types as well. Good point, but I think it's an even more minor edge case than you suggest.

Comment: No doubt. I suspect you'd have a hard time finding a machine on the planet that sported the new integral types yet still had a ones' complement or sign/magnitude `int` type :-)