# Partial output printing for libmodbus functions output

Tags: c, embedded, modbus

I'm writing application using `libmodbus 3.1.2`. 
I'm unable to print complete output of `modbus` functions. Also I'm getting some garbage values in output. Please suggest.

```
 printf("================Sending  Sample delay command==============\n");
  i32_read_ret = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 164, 1, sample_delay);
  printf("\nSample delay result:%d\n", i32_read_ret);
  printf("\n Sample delay : \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) //printing only the received characters
  {
    printf(" : %.2x \t", (int)( * (unsigned char * )( & sample_delay[i])));

  }
  printf("\n\n\n");

  tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
  printf("================Sending  measurement command==============\n");

  i32_read_ret = modbus_write_registers(ctx, 1, 5, measurement);
  printf("\nMeasurement result : %d \n", i32_read_ret);
  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    printf(": %.2x \t", (int)( * (unsigned char * )( & measurement[i])));

  }
  printf("\n");
  tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
  printf("================Sending  actual measurement command==============\n");
  i32_read_ret = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 83, 10, actual_measurement);
  printf("\nRead Return actual_measurement 3:%d\n\n\n", i32_read_ret);

  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) //printing only the received characters
  {
    printf(" : %.2x \t", (int)( * (unsigned char * )( & actual_measurement[i])));

  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("%s\n", actual_measurement);
  tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
```

o/p

```
================Sending  Sample delay command==============
[28][03][00][A4][00][01][C2][10]
Waiting for a confirmation...
<28><03><02><01><2C><E5><CF>

Sample delay result:1

 Sample delay : 
 : 2c    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 08    : 08    : 80    : 00    : 38    : 00    : 29    : 00    : 00    : 00    : c8    : 7d    : 01    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 30    : 00    : 00    : 00   


================Sending  measurement command==============
[28][10][00][01][00][05][0A][B1][D8][77][1E][B1][D8][77][1E][0D][F8][9F][E7]
Waiting for a confirmation...
<28><10><00><01><00><05><56><33>

Measurement result : 5 
: d8    : 1e    : d8    : 1e    : f8    : 00    : 65    : 57    : 70    : 00    : 10    : 02    : 65    : 57    : 7c    : 00    : 00 : 04   : 01    : 00    : 49    : 01    : 31    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00 : 00   : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    
================Sending  actual measurement command==============
[28][03][00][53][00][0A][32][25]
Waiting for a confirmation...
<28><03><14><41><DD><8E><59><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><46><1C><34><00><46><1C><34><00><48><84>

Read Return actual_measurement 3:10


 : dd    : 59    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 1c    : 00    : 1c    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 08    : 1b    : 31    : 00    : 28    : 00    : 08    : 00    : 01    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 00    : 20    : 07    : 00    : 00    : 20    : 07   
�AY�
```

Comment: getting partial ouput for printf. Pls ignore typo mistake in title.

Comment: You should use return values of modbus functions to print the result. `for(i=0;i<40;i++)` --> `for(i=0;i<i32_read_ret ;i++)`.

Comment: tried with same, but still getting same result.       for(i=0;i<i32_read_ret;i++)

Comment: What result? Also how are you defining `actual_measurement`? if it is of type `uint16_t` you cannot use   `printf("%s\n", actual_measurement);` to print as `string`. See [how to print uint16_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112878/how-do-i-printf-a-uint16-t).

Comment: removed line   printf("%s\n", actual_measurement);                       printing with following lines.                                                 
  for(i=0;i<i32_read_ret;i++)  //printing only the received characters
  {
        printf(" : %.2x \t",(int)(*(unsigned char*)(&actual_measurement[i])));
      
       
  }

Comment: Actual output :                                             
          ================Sending  actual measurement command==============
[28][03][00][53][00][0A][32][25] ---- > command
Waiting for a confirmation...
<28><03><14><41><DE><01><49><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><46><1C><34><00><46><1C><34><00><1B><FA> -----> expected output by printf
actual output getting :
Read Return actual_measurement 3:10


 : de   : 49   : 00   : 00   : 00   : 00   : 1c   : 00   : 1c   : 00

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem you are facing as `modbus_read_registers` is reading 10 registers contents as you asked. How is it partial output?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. partial output PRINTING problem resolved after changing printf lines but garbage values problem still persists. :  for(i=0;i<i32_read_ret;i++)  //printing only the received characters
   {
      //  printf(": %.2x \t",(int)(*(unsigned char*)(&measurement[i])));
       printf("%X",sample_delay[i]);
       
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## After correcting line of printf issue got resolved.

```
for(i=0;i<i32_read_ret;i++)
{
   printf("%X",sample_delay[i]);
}
```

Comment: .... so your code is working as expected now? If so, congratulations :) Feel free to accept your own answer as the solution. Otherwise, please edit your original question to reflect the new problems you have encountered (if you have reputation enough to make an edit?)