# converted an integer to short in C, get 4-byte when printed short

Tags: c, integer, short

I converted an integer value to short, but when I printed the hexadecimal result of short, it was shown in 4-bytes, I can't find the reason.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
   int j = 53191;
   short s = (short)j;
   printf("s = %x",s);
}
```

output: `ffffcfc7`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882761/1607937 - you need to use `%hx` -> Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3rG6Y9bsT

Comment: Alos note that `short`s can be 4 bytes long.

Comment: In accordance with @Jean-BaptisteYunès comment, you may want to use the stdint collection of typedefs to make sure that your variables have the value range you are expecting. `int16_t` for a 16Bit signed integer (short), `uint16_t` for an `unsigned short`.

Comment: If it weren't for [default argument promotions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2), you'd be invoking Undefined Behaviour by using `"%x"` (which requires a corresponding `unsigned` value) with a value of type `short`.

Comment: @ᕮ_ᑐᑌᑎᕮ4 No, this isn't a duplicate of those posts since `%hx` assumes an unsigned parameter. `short` is not unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is because the `%x` specifier expects a 32bit integer to be passed (default argument promotion).

The `0xFFFF` prior to the number indicates, that your number is, in fact, negative.
That's because `53191` is above the 'signed threshold' of `short` (which is 32k (-32,768 to 32,767)).

Try it again with a value below 32k or use an `unsigned short` and your result should change accordingly.

Or, alternatively, please refer to the specification of `printf` and use the h specifier prior to the x. (`%hx`) instead, which will tell `printf` to expect a `short`.

(Thanks to Adrian Mole for reminding me)

Comment: O just use the `%hx` format specifier.

Comment: `%hx` will strictly speaking still give UB since the type passed isn't unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `int` is 4 bytes and `short` is 2 bytes, then the value `53191` does not fit inside a short. What happens then isn't well-defined:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So it is up to the compiler to handle this situation as it sees fit. A common implementation is to treat the binary representation of the original type as the corresponding 2's complement representation of the new type. In this case `0xCFC7` which gets treated as a `short` with value -12345.

Next up, `%x` assumes a parameter of type `unsigned int`. `printf("s = %x",s);` is therefore not well-defined either - it's strictly speaking undefined behavior.

In practice, `s` will get promoted as required by "the default argument promotions" that apply to all variadic functions like printf. That is, from `short` to `int`. Then a common non-standard extension is to reinterpret the binary representation of that promoted `int` as unsigned int. In case this happens, we would observe the sign extension that took place during argument promotion, meaning the value would have changed from `0xCFC7` to `0xFFFFCFC7`. But to print an `int` with `%x` isn't guaranteed behavior so we shouldn't rely on it or write code such as this.