# passing a pointer member in structure which is member of another structure to a function which accepts double pointer

Tags: c, struct

I have to pass a double pointer to a function

```
struct Animal{
        uint_32 *count; 
}


struct forest{
      struct Animal elephant;
}

void pass(uint32 **count){
       printf("Count:%d\n",**count);
}

int main(){
   struct  forest *gir;
   gir=(struct forest*)malloc(sizeof(struct forest));
   gir.elephant.count=(int*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

   pass(_______); //have to pass count value
       return 0;
}
```

I have tried various combos but not sure how to handle this case.

---

kindly note, I have directly written it on SO, as putting up actual code would be unnecessarily complicating, as I am only looking for specific solution.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/cCVrIU)

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

```
pass(&gir->elephant.count);
```

You need to pass the address of `count` in `elephant` in `gir`.

One of your line can't compile:

```
// gir.elephant.count=(int *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)); this one
gir->elephant.count = malloc(sizeof *gir->elephant.count);
if (gir->elephant.count == NULL) { // you should always check the return of malloc
    free(gir);
    return 1;
}
gir->elephant.count = 42; // maybe you want affect count to something?
```

Plus you forget `;` at the end of your structure declaration. And `uint_32`, don't exist in [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html), you must use `uint32_t`. @chux notice that you don't use the correct flag to print a `uint32_t` in `printf()`, you must use [`PRIu32`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12120500/7076153).

```
struct Animal {
    uint32_t *count; 
};

struct forest {
    struct Animal elephant;
};

void pass(uint32_t **count)
   printf("Count:%" PRIu32 "\n", **count);
}
```

---

You shoud not [cast return of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: thanks, I wrote this directly on so, hence the error

Comment: I find myself UV-ing `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n);` answers - it is so simple.  Good answer.

Comment: BTW  `printf("Count:%d\n",**count);` needs work. Sign-ness and width issues.

Comment: @HimanshuSourav You should not fix your issues by editing your question that destroy my answer.

Comment: @Stargateur reverted