# How do I print array of u16 in C?

Tags: c, linux, hex

I'd like to print both MSB and LSB of a u16 variable, here is my code:

```
__u16 reg = 0x10A0; /* Device register to access */
__s32 res;
char buf[10];

buf[0] = reg;

printf("0x%X\n", buf[0]);
```

This code just print the LSB part in hexa format, but can you tell me how do I print the MSB part?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `>>` operator and bitmasking? Have you tried casting to `unsigned char*` and treating it as bytes?

Comment: If you want to print the value of `reg` without splitting into bytes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12120500/10622916

Comment: Also, do you wish to print the address or the contents? Printing the address seems mildly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code just print the LSB part

Well of course, `buf[0] = reg;` only copies 8 bits.

And what result you get isn't well-defined, because `char` cannot reliably store raw binary. It might be signed on your systems and then you can get all kinds of subtle bugs because of it.

Step 1 is to fix your types. Get rid of `char` as well as the home-made, garage standard integer types, in favour for standard C types:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t reg = 0x10A0u; 
uint8_t  buf [10];
```

Then decide the byte order of your array. Assuming that you want index 0 to be the most significant byte, then the quick & dirty version looks like this:

```
buf[0] = reg >> 8;
buf[1] = reg;
```

This will work in this specific case. However, good compilers will moan about implicit promotions and similar. Strictly speaking, you should make a habit of always casting to `uint32_t` before doing any kind of shifting (assuming >=32 bit system). We can make the code more rugged and silence warnings like this:

```
buf[0] = ((uint32_t)reg >> 8) & 0xFFu;
buf[1] = ((uint32_t)reg >> 0) & 0xFFu;
```

This method safely scales to larger types as well.

Also, be vary of various quack solutions on SO and elsewhere telling you to use `union` or character pointers for this. Such solutions make the code needlessly endianess dependent for nothing gained. The shift version is 100% portable even across different endianess CPUs.

Then finally, printing with `printf`. You can get the correct format specifier for any *uintn_t* automatically from the header `inttypes.h`. It provides `PRIx8` for lower case hex and `PRIX8` for upper case hex.

Complete program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  uint16_t reg = 0x10A0u; 
  uint8_t  buf[10];

  buf[0] = ((uint32_t)reg >> 8) & 0xFFu;
  buf[1] = ((uint32_t)reg >> 0) & 0xFFu;

  printf("0x%"PRIX8 "%"PRIX8 "\n", buf[0], buf[1]);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except I differ in part: "Strictly speaking, you should make a habit of always casting to uint32_t before doing any kind of shifting (assuming >=32 bit system)" --> To not not get moaning and not rely on that assumption for the 16-bit `reg`, code could use `buf[0] = ((unsigned)reg >> 8) & 0xFFu;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah... I'm too used at always writing MISRA-compliant code I guess. `unsigned` isn't allowed by MISRA-C since you should always use the stdint.h types. But I agree that in your example it actually makes the code more portable.

Comment: "MISRA-C" --> how to write code and remain as C89-like as possible compatible.  I feel for you

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Eh, well not really since they love `stdint.h` which is C99. Even the old MISRA-C:2004 which only covered C90 pushed for using `stdint.h` or equivalent typedefs.

Comment: Agree about love for `stdint.h`, but it is not for desire to embrace C99 - more of a means to fix the C language to a non-evolving standard. Either at some point MISRA needs to evolve else it is dead weight to the progress of C.

Comment: We certainly agree on some areas:  _bounds-checking interface_, easier to bloat than remove warts.  I hope for Unicode improvements.  Thanks for your insights.

Comment: All those `& 0xFFu` are redundant when the lvalue type is `uint8_t`.