# printing the uint8_t

Tags: c, debugging

I have `uint8_t  orig[ETH_ALEN];`

How can I print it using `__printf(3, 4)`

which is defined as `#define __printf(a, b)                  __attribute__((format(printf, a, b)))`

the Orig should be ethernet hardware address.

Comment: `%u` works for any `uintN_t`, I think, or at least `uint8_t`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format specifiers for uint8\_t, uint16\_t, ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993132/format-specifiers-for-uint8-t-uint16-t)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to construct a format string that's suitable. The `printf()` function has no way of printing an array in one go, so you need to split it and print each `uint8_t`:

```
__printf("MAC: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",
         orig[0] & 0xff, orig[1] & 0xff, orig[2] & 0xff,
         orig[3] & 0xff, orig[4] & 0xff, orig[5] & 0xff);
```

The `& 0xff` is to ensure only 8 bits are sent to `printf()`; they shouldn't be needed for an unsigned type like `uint8_t` though so you can try without too.

This assumes a regular 48-bit MAC, and prints using the [conventional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Notational_conventions) colon-separated hex style.

Comment: `uint8_t` is guaranteed to only have 8 bits so the mask is unnecessary. But, even then more than 8 bits will be sent anyway because `printf` is variadic so they will all be promoted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @dreamlax All values of a `uint8_t` are representable as an `int`, so the integer promotions [and hence default argument promotions] will promote `uint8_t` to `int`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: D'oh that's what I meant... the `unsigned` came out of nowhere. What I meant was more than 8 bits will be given to printf because of integer promotion.

Answer (score 21):

Use C99 format specifiers:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", orig[0]);
```

Comment: you are missing the "%" before the macro, I think.

Comment: in VC2013, its defined as %u