# How do I convert a byte stream to unsigned int 8 in C

Tags: c, python-3.x, websocket, ctypes, bytestream

I am streaming a video in python via WebSocket, which is a raw bytes stream and appears like this:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01A\x9a \x02\x04\xe1{=z\xf8FMS\xe6\\\x9eMubH\xa7R.1\xd7]F\xea3}\xa9b\x9f\x14n\x12| ....'
```

Now, I am passing these bytes to a C function (via ctypes) where I am trying to convert this to a uint8_t [] array (This is needed in order to decode it using a FFmpeg library). Here's my code so far:

This is how I am passing bytes to C:

```py
 import ctypes
 dll = ctypes.CDLL("decode_video.so")
 data = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01A\x9a \x02\x04\xe1-{=z\xf8FM....')
 b_array = ctypes.c_char * len(data)
 dll.conversion_test(b_array.from_buffer(data), len(data))
```

decode_video.c

```c
void conversion_test(unsigned char* buf, int bufSize) {
    char temp[3]; 
    uint8_t vals[bufSize];

    // Iterate over the values
    for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++) {
        // Copy two characters into the temporary string
        temp[0] = buf[i * 2];
        temp[1] = buf[i * 2 + 1];

        temp[2] = 0;
        vals[i] = strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<bufSize; i++){
        printf("%02x ", vals[i] & 0xff);
    }

}
```

Aside from this, I am simultaneously dumping the stream to a file. In C, I have another function that reads from this file and stores in a uint8_t buffer.

Streaming code in python:

```py
f = open("video.h264", "wb")
def on_message(ws, message):
    # The first 14 characters have irrelevant info to decode the video
    f.write(message[14:])

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://somewebsite.com/archives",
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close,
                                header=[protocol_str]
                                )
ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'
ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)
```

Reading from the raw file in C:

```c
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#define INBUF_SIZE 4096
uint8_t *data;
uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
f = fopen(input_name, "rb");
data_size = fread(inbuf, 1, INBUF_SIZE, f);

// Printing bytes in hex to debug
for(size_t i=0; i<data_size; i++){
     printf("%02x ", inbuf[i] & 0xff);
}
```

However the contents of this `inbuf` and output of the `vals` buffer are not the same. Basically, I am unsure of my method of passing bytes to C and its corresponding coversion to uint8_t.

**Update:**

I tried printing the hex values of `vals` and here's what it looks like:
`00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 ...`

While the output of `inbuf` looks like this:
`00 00 00 01 67 42 00 1e e2 90 14 07 b6 02 dc ...`

Comment: I recommend you use a *debugger* to take a look at the actual data in `buf`. Are you sure it's passed as *text* not actual bytes?

Comment: hmmm... the text talks about "byte stream" but the code seems to expect a stream of characters, i.e. it seems `conversion_test` takes two characters put them together to form a string and then converts the string to a number. hmm... raw byte streams are very different from character streams. Please clarify ....

Comment: `printf("%c", vals[i]);` is not the correct way to print `uint8_t`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358967/printing-the-uint8-t

Comment: "I am simultaneously dumping the stream to a file" How exactly are you doing that? Because you didn't post any code doing so and that's likely where the problem is.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I followed the thread to print out the values in ```val``` buffer. I to compared this output with the ```hex()``` method in python, and they don't match. I believe like the ```unsigned char* buf``` isn't exactly receiving bytes.

Comment: @Arbaaz I only know a little python. I have never tried calling a C function from python. So I can't tell you how the python data will show up in the C function. I think you are trying to do too much at one time. I would start up with some very simple python data. Pass it to a C function that only prints the data as raw data using e.g. `%x` By keeping it simple you will probably be able to figure out how that interfacing work.

Comment: Byres and uint8_t are essentially the same, your conversion should be the identity function.

Comment: Not sure whether this is the culprit, but it's definitely something wrong: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: `// Copy two characters into the temporary string` Why?!?! It's a *byte* array.  Just print it:  `for(int i=0; i<bufSize; i++){
        printf("%02hhx ", buf[i]);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix:

As suggested by @n. m. and @dreamlax, a simple identity mapping works between unsigned char and uint8_t. Now vals and inbuf output the same values!

```
void conversion_test(unsigned char* buf, int bufSize) {
    uint8_t vals[bufSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++)
        vals[i] = (uint8_t)buf[i];
}
```

(OR) A simple type-casting

```
uint8_t *vals = (uint8_t *)ubuf;
```