# How to convert uint16_t to a wide string (std::wstring)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

My question is related to this older question
[Format specifiers for uint8_t, uint16_t, ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993132/format-specifiers-for-uint8-t-uint16-t)

Just to recap the original question was related to how to use the specifiers for uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and uint64_t with a scanf?

The answer to the question was as follows:

```
sscanf (line, "Value of integer: %" SCNd32 "\n", &my_integer);
```

But does anyone know how to do this but resulting in a wide string?

ie

```
std::wstring line;
swscanf (line.c_str(), L"Value of integer: %" SCNd16 L"\n", &my_integer);
```

The sbove line gives me a concatenating error. I believe because the SCNd16 is just not intended for a widestring?

Currently my solution is to create the std::string in the original answer and then convert it to a wide string

```
sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%" SCNd16 "\n", &sixteenBitInteger)
// code here to check for EOF and EINVAL
//then I convert it 
typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> ConverterType; 
std::wstring_convert<ConverterType, wchar_t> converter;
std::wstring convertedString = converter.from_bytes(line);
```

but it's rather ugly and I am sure there must be a more polished way to do this conversion? 
If it helps to understand my use, I am using the uint16_t type to store the port number for a web server but I want to be able to convert it to a wide string as that is the expected display type. I am also using C++11 if that changes the answer at all and I do have access to the boost libraries although I would rather not use them.

Comment: SCNd16 is just a define, so if for you it is not critical to have cross-platform/architecture code just lookup its value and enter after % in your swscanf string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [VS2013 compiler bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816826/error-c2308-concatenating-mismatched-strings-given-when-it-shouldnt-be). Since it has been closed as "fixed", maybe it'll work in VS2015 (don't have the preview installed to give it a try).

The line of code you have

```
swscanf (line.c_str(), L"Value of integer: %" SCNd16 L"\n", &my_integer);
```

is well formed, because even if `SCNd16` expands to a string literal that lacks the `L` prefix, the standard says that if out of two adjacent string literals, one lacks an encoding prefix, it is treated as if it has the same encoding prefix as the other.

*§2.14.5/14* **[lex.string]**

> In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated. If both string literals have the same *encoding-prefix*, the resulting concatenated string literal has that *encoding-prefix*. If one string literal has no *encoding-prefix*, it is treated as a string literal of the same *encoding-prefix* as the other operand. `...`

---

Typically, you can use the preprocessor to widen strings by using token concatenation. For instance, defining a set of macros like this

```
#define WIDEN_(x) L##x
#define WIDEN(x) WIDEN_(x)
```

and converting the offending line of code to

```
swscanf (line.c_str(), L"Value of integer: %" WIDEN(SCNd16) L"\n", &my_integer);
```

would fix the problem, but it doesn't on VS2013 because of an implementation detail. The `SCNd16` macro actually expands into two separate string literals - `"h" "d"`. So the above macro widens the first literal, but not the second, and you run into the same (bogus) error.

Your options are to either hardcode the string `"hd"` or go with the runtime conversion solution you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

A pure guess as I don't have time at the moment to try it.

Can you use the preprocesser to token paste the wide-string L to the front of the expanded SCNd16?